# Skip sending cookies in request, but maintain cookies

Tags: android, cookies, request, httpclient

Is there a simple way to make sure the HttpClient does not send the cookies during a request, without removing all cookies.

By doing:

```
httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();
```

cookies are not sent, which is good.
But for other requests (where I need those cookies), I don't want to fetch new cookies again.

Comment: I don't know android, but have you access to localStorage option? Or internal db in order to "backup" cookie. Another solution could be make cookie valid only for a certain path (and make request without cookie in another path)

Comment: Hi, good suggestion but unfortunately not applicable for my issue. And to manually update and handle cookies in DB is not something that should be considered.

Comment: I think there are no other ways. Because it's the concept of cookie. You can also set another domain for no cookie requests. It's the trick for the static images in very big system (facebook, google etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the Cookie header of the request manually for that particular request

```
request.setHeader("Cookie","");
```

Edited:
So if is that not working an other approach could be to try to add an empty cookie store to that HttpClient instance, so theoretically you will have an empty cookiestore

```
// Create a local instance of cookie store
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
// Add the created cookieStore to the http client instance
httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Comment: Tried this without any luck. Seems like the httpClient automatically adds cookies for the domain, even if we add empty cookies in header.

Answer (score 0):

My response is based on assumption that you are using Apache HttpClient version 4.x.

By default HttpClient 4.x introduces two protocol interceptors to the protocol processing pipeline responsible for HTTP state management: `RequestAddCookies` and `ResponseProcessCookies`. What you want is to remove `RequestAddCookies` while leaving `ResponseProcessCookies` in place.

This is how this can be done with HttpClient 4.3

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .disableCookieManagement()
        .addInterceptorFirst(new ResponseProcessCookies())
        .build();
```

There are other ways to achieve the same result such as using a custom protocol interceptor that removes cookie headers from all outgoing requests, but removal of `RequestAddCookies` is the most efficient.